# Replace place holders with values in a message - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript message object like below,which has some place holders like below.

```
{
    message: "This is a Sample message with some placeholder values like {placeHolder1}, {placeHolder2} ad {placeHolder3}"
    "context_types": [
        "placeHolder1",
        "placeHolder2",
        "placeHolder3"
    ],
    "context_values": [
        "Value1",
        "Value2",
        "Value3"
    ]
}
```

The final message should be

```
This is a Sample message with some placeholder values like Value1, Value2 ad Value3
```

I need to do this for array of objects. guys help me out on this ,need to have a util function for converting this.

Comment: It would be a lot cleaner if `context` was an object like so: `{ message: "...", context: { placeholder1: value1, placeholder2: value2, ... } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex replace with a callback. A `/\{(.+?)\}/g` will do. It looks for sub-strings like that match `"{text here}"`, it groups the text inside `{` and `}` to get it as a separate argument of the callback, it also uses the non-greedy/lazy quantifier `.+?`.

After that just use plain old `indexOf` to get the index of the value.

```
function getMessage(obj) {
    return obj.message.replace(/\{(.+?)\}/g, function(match, placeholder) { // go over all placeholders in the string
        var index = obj.context_types.indexOf(placeholder);                 // get the index of the current placeholder from the context_types array
        if(index !== -1) {                                                  // if this placeholder exists
            return obj.context_values[index];                               // return the value that corresponds to it
        }
        return match;                                                       // otherwise return match which will not replace the current placeholder in the resulting string, you can use a different return value like "undefined" to signal placeholder not found
    });
}
```

**demo:**

```js
function getMessage(obj) {
  return obj.message.replace(/\{(.+?)\}/g, function(match, placeholder) {
    var index = obj.context_types.indexOf(placeholder);
    if (index !== -1) {
      return obj.context_values[index];
    }
    return match;
  });
}


const obj = {
  message: "This is a Sample message with some placeholder values like {placeHolder1}, {placeHolder2} ad {placeHolder3}",
  "context_types": [
    "placeHolder1",
    "placeHolder2",
    "placeHolder3"
  ],
  "context_values": [
    "Value1",
    "Value2",
    "Value3"
  ]
}

console.log(getMessage(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the array and use `String#replace`, as long as the placeholder values do not have any regular expression metacharacters.

```js
const obj = {
    message: "This is a Sample message with some placeholder values like {placeHolder1}, {placeHolder2} ad {placeHolder3}",
    "context_types": [
        "placeHolder1",
        "placeHolder2",
        "placeHolder3"
    ],
    "context_values": [
        "Value1",
        "Value2",
        "Value3"
    ]
}
let str = obj.message;
obj.context_types.forEach((placeholder,idx)=>str=str.replace(new RegExp("{"+placeholder+"}", "g"), obj.context_values[idx]));
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
    message: "This is a Sample message with some placeholder values like {placeHolder1}, {placeHolder2} and {placeHolder3}",
    "context_types": [
        "placeHolder1",
        "placeHolder2",
        "placeHolder3"
    ],
    "context_values": [
        "Value1",
        "Value2",
        "Value3"
       ]
}

function generate(data) {
  const message = data.message.split(/{\w+}/g).slice(0, -1);
  return message.reduce((string, ele, i) => string += ele += data.context_values[i], "");
}

console.log(generate(data));
```