# Javascript replace string $n with array values

Tags: javascript

So I have this string:

```
const myStr = 'Hi $1, please check your $2 account status by clicking the link below';
const data = ['John', 'bank'];
```

I want to replace $1 with John and $2 with bank. But I want it to be flexible so I can have more parameters, like $3, $4 and so on. The array will always be as long as the amount of $n ocurrences.

Comment: What have you tried so far to meet these requirements? Stack Overflow won't write your code for you - include your attempt as a [mre], along with an explanation of why it doesn't meet your requirements, by editing your question. See also: [ask]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926203/replace-place-holders-with-values-in-a-message-javascript

Comment: I didn't give `-1` as I think it's a valid question and I am not a fan of "what have you tried?", but just iterate through the array of replacements and use `.replace()` ?

Comment: @FlashThunder oh that's smart, I was thinking regex but I'm terrible with regex, I'll write a function quickly and answer it, maybe it's not the most efficient but it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the array length and the number of occurrences ($1, $2, etc) are the same in every case then you can do:

```js
const myStr = 'Hi $1, please check your $2 account status by clicking the link below';
const data = ['John', 'bank'];

function interpolate(string, arr) {
    arr.forEach((item, index) => (string = string.replace(`$${index + 1}`, item)))
    return string
}


// Call it to see the result
const result = interpolate(myStr, data);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi, yeah someone above mentioned this approach and I built a function exactly like yours, I was thinking I'd have to use regex but to me this is more legible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression that matches `$` followed by digits. Then use a replacement function that gets the digits and uses them as an array index.

```js
const myStr = 'Hi $1, please check your $2 account status by clicking the link below';
const data = ['John', 'bank'];

const result = myStr.replace(/\$(\d+)/g, (match, num) => data[num - 1]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only an answer to the Nadir Abbas solution (that is not that clear imo and maybe not that efficient) ...

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
   myStr = myStr.replace("$" + (i + 1), data[i]);
}
```

Comment: yep, mine one is cleaner, but less efficient. Also, `replaceAll` doesn't have very good browser support. I guess we can use RegExp instead?

Comment: yeah I meant exactly the opposite :) it depends if there could be more than one `$1` for example... but I guess not. If so, regex could be used in my solution as well. I edited the `repleaceAll` as it wasn't needed. I am pretty sure it's much faster and more clear.

Comment: @NadirAbbas only so You read my edit :) sorry for the mess

Comment: Yes, you're right. $1 is going to come only once.

Comment: `for(var i=1; i<=data.length; i++){...}`

Comment: @VXp in JavaScript array indexing starts with 0. But You are right about the $i + 1 replacement, edited, thanx.

Comment: Not just in JS..., $0 wouldn't replace anything, glad that you've edited, but could also make it `data[i-1]`.

Comment: @VXp in some languages it actually starts with 1... I know it's weird :)

Comment: Just for others... Languages of which array indexing starts with one (some are really popular, like `R`, `Matlab`, `Fotran`): ALGOL 98
APL
AWK
CFML
COBOL
Fortran
FoxPro
Julia
Lingo
Lua
Mathematica
Matlab
PL/I
RPG
R
Ring
Sass
Smalltalk
Wolfram Language
XPath/ XQuery

Comment: I think not starting with 0 is a sin.